# PayPal .NET SDK 1.7.2 - Express Checkout?

Tags: paypal, nuget-package, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-soap

Does the PayPal .NET SDK 1.7.2 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal/) support Express Checkout? I can't seem to find it in the sample code.

If not, does it provide another mechanism to take payment on an ecommerce site?

Or should I be using the PayPal Merchant SDK for .NET 2.16.117 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalMerchantSDK/)

There was a note on github about the merchant SDK being deprecated due to the TLS/SSL changes coming down the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `REST Api` (your first link) calls it [`Paypal Payment`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) - you'll recognize the *flow* maps to the "classic" Express Checkout (but obviously with a new implementation). Hth...

Comment: Awesome thanks. Is this the right API to use? Or is there a better way to implement Express Checkout?

Comment: @TomasBeblar Depends on what you mean by "better"..it's _not_ the only way to implement Express Checkout, you can use "Classic" NVP/SOAP. I _personally_ prefer [In Context](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/) which IINM uses "classic" API (nvp/soap) _only_ - if it meets your requirements and/or are eligible for it..Hth...